# How to find the n-th term of a GP in Scheme using recurrence?

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm trying to find the N-th Term of a GP using recursive algorithm in Scheme but I encounter this error.
" Interactions disabled; out of memory "
The first term is a, r is the common ratio and n is the nth term of the sequence.
The n-th term is a* r^(n-1).
So (nth 4 2 2) must return 16. (2, 4, 8, **16**) where a=2 and r=2.

```
( define (nth n r a)
   (cond
     ((eq? n 0) 1)
     ((eq? r 0) #f)
     ( * a (nth (- n 1) r a))
   )
   )
```

Comment: What is the base case? That is, how does your recursive process stop?

Comment: You should also explain what you think a GP is, and how your function's arguments represent one.

Comment: [apparently](https://www.google.com/search?q=N-th+Term+of+a+GP)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you mean geometric progression, where

```
Tn     =  a*rn-1        -- and so, also
Tn-1   =  a*rn-2        -- and thus
Tn     =  Tn-1 * r, 
          Tn-1  =  Tn-2 * r, 
             ......., 
                     T1  =  a*r0  =  a
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code had no base case, and that is why it ended in an out-of-memory error. The recursive process had no defined stopping point, so it ran until there was no more memory available.

Despite what the question claims, the updated code does not run out of memory; but the code is incorrect.

The updated code returns 1 for `(nth 4 2 2)`:

```
(define (nth n r a)
  (cond
    ((eq? n 0) 1)
    ((eq? r 0) #f)
    (* a (nth (- n 1) r a))))
```

```
gp.rkt> (nth 4 2 2)
1
```

The problem is the final [*conditional clause*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=cond#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29): `(* a (nth (- n 1) r a))`.

A conditional clause is a parenthesized expression containing a test expression and one or more body expressions, i.e., `(<test-exp> <body-exp> ...+)`. In the posted code `*` takes the place of the `<test-exp>`, and always evaluates to true. Then the remaining expressions are evaluated. Since the last of those expressions is a recursive call to `nth`, the process continues until `n` is zero, at which point 1 is returned. There are no further operations performed on the returned value (since `*` is evaluated as a test expression, and the value of `a` is thrown away), so `nth` will *always* return 1 for non-negative `n` and positive `r`.

What is needed to fix this is an `else` clause:

```
(define (nth n r a)
  (cond ((eq? n 0) 1)
        ((eq? r 0) #f)
        (else
         (* a (nth (- n 1) r a)))))
```

```
gp.rkt> (nth 4 2 2)
16
```

Incidentally, `eq?` is ordinarily not the right comparison to use with numbers. In Racket it works for [fixnums](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/numbers.html?q=fixnums), and it works here because the inputs are exact integer types which are compared to exact integer types. In other lisps this is not likely to work as expected. Usually you should use [`=`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=%3D#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._%7E3d%29%29) for number comparisons, or even [`zero?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html?q=zero%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._zero%7E3f%29%29) to compare a number with zero.

Ordinarily I would use `zero?` for this because it is the most specific procedure for this use:

```
(define (nth n r a)
  (cond ((zero? n) 1)
        ((zero? r) #f)
        (else
         (* a (nth (- n 1) r a)))))
```